# No overload matches delegate when trying to add method to watcher

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to make `changed` be called every time when there is a change in my resource group.

I am doing

```
AppResourceGroupInfoWatcher watcher = app.CreateResourceGroupWatcher();
watcher.Added += changed;
watcher.Start();
```

In the same class I have:

```
public void changed(TypedEventHandler<AppResourceGroupInfoWatcher, AppResourceGroupInfoWatcherEventArgs> a)
{

}
```

But still, even though I have this TypedEventHandler, I get `No overload for 'changed' matches delegate 'TypedEventHandler<AppResourceGroupInfoWatcher, AppResourceGroupInfoWatcherEventArgs>'`. Is there something wrong with this approach? Is there a better way to run a function every time the Execution state of an app changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegates are applied against the method signature, not the method parameters. So

```
public void changed(AppResourceGroupInfoWatcher sender, AppResourceGroupInfoWatcherEventArgs args)
{
 /// Your logic
}
```